# How to navigate to specific navigator from nested screen

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

Right now I have below set up

App.js

```html
  const mainStack = createStackNavigator();

  return (
    <AuthProvider>
      <NavigationContainer ref={navigationRef}>
        <mainStack.Navigator>
          {!isUserAvailable ? (
            <mainStack.Screen name="Auth" component={AuthentificationStack}/>
          ) : (
            <mainStack.Screen
              name="Core"
              component={CoreApplicationStack}
              initialParams={{isBakerySetUp: hasBakery}}
            />
          )}
        </mainStack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    </AuthProvider>
  );
```

AuthentificationStack.js

```html
  const AuthStack = createStackNavigator();

  return (
    <AuthStack.Navigator>
      <AuthStack.Screen name="Welcome" component={WelcomeScreen} />
      <AuthStack.Screen
        name="SignUp"
        component={SignupScreen}
        options={({navigation}) => {
          return {
            headerRight: () => <SignUpHeader navigation={navigation} />,
          };
        }}
      />
      <AuthStack.Screen name="Login" component={LogInScreen} />
      <AuthStack.Screen name="PhoneNumber" component={PhoneNumberScreen}/>
    </AuthStack.Navigator>
  );
```

My struggle is that I am unable to navigate to 'Core' navigator stack from 'Auth' => 'PhoneNumber' screen. I also tried to utilize the navigationRef that I created for the App.js 's stack navigator; however, I cannot navigate to 'Core' stack navigator.

I also do update isUserAvailable (from asyncStorage), but as App.js is not rendered, that logic of switching to Core stack navigator does not apply.

Is there any way for me to navigate to 'Core' navigator from 'Auth''s nested screen?

Comment: Can you please add the code of how you are navigating to "Core" stack from "Auth" stack ?

Comment: From Auth's PhoneNumber screen, I am calling navigation.navigate('Core'). The navigation prop here only belongs to Auth's stack navigator, so cannot navigate to 'Core'